# Get XML data cross-domain namecheap.com API

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, http-get

I am trying to use the namecheap.com API to allow domain searches from my website but I am stuck at the old problem of cross-domain blocking. On the [API documentation](http://www.namecheap.com/support/api/api.aspx) it says that I need to make a HTTP-GET request to retrieve the XML file. I've done this in jQuery but I get the cross-domain error message. When I changed the dataType to jsonp like below, it gets the XML file but causes an error because the browser isn't expecting an XML file.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: 'https://api.sandbox.namecheap.com/xml.response',
  data: {ApiUser: 'user', ApiKey: 'keygoeshere', UserName: 'user', Command: 'namecheap.domains.check',  DomainList: 'test.com, dfuhkgusvhbksbhv.com', ClientIp: '123.1.1.123'},
  success: parseXml
});
```

Can someone please explain how I would do this and be able to fetch the XML file without any errors?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: When you specify a `jsonp` dataType jQuery expects JSON data. Are there any parts about handling cross domain ajax in the docs?

Comment: Nope, the documenation isn't very good. I've tried PHP simplexml_load_file() instead and that's working OK, is the cross-domain thing just related to Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: You cannot access cross-domain data (JSONP being a workaround as it will inject a script element - which is allowed - that supplies the data) with JavaScript. It might turn out that this API is only accessible via server side scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used simplexml_load_file() function in PHP instead and this worked OK without any cross-browser issues. API works fine using this method.

Comment: Not a solution, since there can't be any cross-domain problem on server-side calls.